# Expand Range of Numbers in SQL

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2016

Is there an SQL code that can be written to expand these cluster of numbers in the Destination Zip Range column?
*Screenshot is  attached below*

Using Access 2016, thanks

[image: Access Snapshot]

Comment: Do you mean PPKLaneID? If yes, then set to IDENTITY

Comment: @LukaszSzozda no sorry, I mean the Destination Zip Range column.

Comment: @LukStorms yes Access 2016

Comment: What do you mean by "expand these clusters of numbers"?

Comment: @Shawn I want to write a code that will create new rows and enter each number in the range. (ex: 850, 851, 852, 853,.. etc) in new rows.

Comment: Are you creating a new table to hold all of the numbers (like a reference table)? Or do you plan to just add new rows to the existing table for each number in the range?

Comment: @Shawn I am planning for it to add to a new table that I have already coded for in my current database, so the issue of referencing a new table isnt needed, I have it already referenced in another code, I just want to add code to that that will expand my ranges and output them in my new table

Answer (score 1):

You will need DAO to run this.

Create a helper function to split the zip codes:

```
Public Function ExpandCluster(ByVal ClusterList As String) As Variant

    Dim Clusters    As Variant
    Dim Items       As Variant
    Dim ZipCodes()  As String

    Dim Index       As Integer
    Dim FirstCode   As Integer
    Dim LastCode    As Integer
    Dim ThisCode    As Integer
    Dim Redimmed    As Boolean

    Clusters = Split(ClusterList, ",")
    ReDim ZipCodes(0)
    For Index = LBound(Clusters) To UBound(Clusters)
        Items = Split(Clusters(Index), "-")
        FirstCode = Val(Items(LBound(Items)))
        LastCode = Val(Items(UBound(Items)))
        While FirstCode <= LastCode
            Debug.Print Index, FirstCode
            If Redimmed Then
                ReDim Preserve ZipCodes(UBound(ZipCodes) + 1)
            Else
                Redimmed = True
            End If
            ZipCodes(UBound(ZipCodes)) = Format(FirstCode, "000")
            FirstCode = FirstCode + 1
        Wend
    Next

    ExpandCluster = ZipCodes

End Function
```

Then use this in a function where you create a record for each zip code extracted with that function:

```
Public Sub FillTable()

    Dim Source      As DAO.Recordset
    Dim Target      As DAO.Recordset

    Dim ZipCodes()  As String
    Dim Index       As Integer

    Set Source = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Select * From tblParent Where ZipRange Is Not Null")
    Set Target = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Select * From tblChild")

    While Not Source.EOF
        ZipCodes = ExpandCluster(Source!ZipRange.Value)
        For Index = LBound(ZipCodes) To UBound(ZipCodes)
            Target.AddNew
                ' Assign foreign key.
                Target!FK.Value = Source!Id.Value
                ' Assign this zip code.
                Target!ZipCode.Value = ZipCodes(Index)
                '
                ' Insert lines for other field values. 
                '
            Target.Update
        Next
        Source.MoveNext
    Wend
    Source.Close
    Target.Close

End Sub
```

Some generic names are used. Of course, adjust these to your actual table and field names.